# ImageMagick in VS2012 - 'identifier not found'

Tags: visual-studio-2012, imagemagick

I'm trying to use ImageMagick Library for a C Project in VS2012. I installed the Library from here: [klick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php)

Then in my Project, I added D:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16\include\ to the include folders.
Then I tried to use Magick with an example code from here:
[http://www.graphicsmagick.org/1.2/www/api.html]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <magick/api.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
InitializeMagick(*argv);
GetExceptionInfo(&exception);
... ...
}
```

Then VS2012 returns errors when I try to compile:

```
error C3861: “InitializeMagick”: identifier not found
error C3861: “GetExceptionInfo”: identifier not found
error C3861: “DestroyMagick”: identifier not found
```

Is there any steps I missed?

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `.lib` files to the linker.

Like setting the header include, open **Properties** -> **Linker** -> **Additional Library Directories**, and add path to `.lib` files. Then add `CORE_RL_magick_.lib` & `CORE_RL_wand_.lib` files to be linked against.

[image: Link path]

**An even *easier* approach.**

Just drag and drop said `.lib`'s from explore into the Solution Explorer.

[image: Drag and drop]

Comment: @RobberJohn `InitializeMagick` & `GetExceptionInfo` have been deprecated. Setting `MAGICKCORE_EXCLUDE_DEPRECATED` definition  under C/C++ pre-processor will include them (see `deprecate.h` file.) But it might be better to follow the [MagickCore docs.](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-core.php)

Comment: Thanks. I have searched the API and source code, and it seems that InitializeMagick and GetExceptionInfo is in it's C++ function. I replaced it with     a C edition like MagickCoreGenesis and AcquireExceptionInfo, then run successfully.